# Which DLC or editions of Dark Souls are available for different platforms?

Tags: dark-souls

I own DarkSouls for the PS3 and I understand there is a DLC however on my PC i saw a Dark Souls Prepare to Die Edition. Is the prepare to die edition the same thing i have with a DLC?

Can someone please list the DLC names or editions available for consoles / PS3?

Comment: This is easily searchable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Souls#PC_version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the console version of Dark Souls, there is only the original and the Prepare to Die edition which is sort of like a game of the year edition with the DLC Artorios of the Abys quest line (not sure on spelling at this point) already installed. That questline is the only Downloadable content for dark souls at this point.